# What will happen when there are less threads than number of tasks for invokeAll()?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have below code:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                                                10, // corePoolSize
                                                10, // maximumPoolSize
                                                10, // keepAliveTime
                                                TimeUnit.SECONDS, 
                                                new LinkedBlockingQueue<>()
                                        );

final List<Callable<MyResponse>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(concurrency);

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    tasks.add(() -> {
        latch.countDown();
        latch.await();

        return getResponse(); // Returns a MyResponse object.
    });
}

final List<Future<ThrottleResponse>> futures = threadPoolExecutor.invokeAll(tasks);
```

There are 50 tasks but only 10 threads available. Based on my test results, the code takes forever to run, which I don't understand.

What happens to the `invokeAll` method? Is there any dead lock in this code and why? I think the `threadPoolExecutor` would put pending tasks in the `LinkedBlockingQueue` and poll from the queue to execute the tasks, so there should be no dead lock right?

Comment: I think you answered your own question.

Comment: @shmosel But I don't understand why there is a dead lock in this case...

Comment: Because there aren't enough threads...

Comment: @shmosel I think the threadPoolExecutor would put pending tasks in the LinkedBlockingQueue and poll from the queue to execute the tasks, so there should be no dead lock right?

Comment: It'll poll the queue once it completes the previous tasks, but the latch won't let them complete until they all start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal behavior for an executor service is to start a task on each available worker in the pool, and put any others onto the queue to wait for a worker to be available.

What you have done is to write tasks that so not complete until all other tasks have started.  Since you have 10 workers, the first 10 tasks each start on a worker .... and then wait.  The first 10 can't finish because they are waiting for other tasks to start, and other tasks can't start because the executor is waiting for a worker to be free ... and that won't happen until one of the first 10 tasks finished.  Deadlock.

---

You commented:

> I think the threadPoolExecutor would put pending tasks in the LinkedBlockingQueue and poll from the queue to execute the tasks, so there should be no dead lock right?

All the tasks are being queued correctly.  The problem is in what the tasks themselves are doing after they have been queued; see explanation above.

---

Solutions:

- Don't design your tasks to wait for the other tasks to start.  (It is not clear from your example why you are doing this, but I doubt that it is really necessary.)
- If you have to wait for the other tasks to start, increase the thread pool size so that it is big enough to run all tasks *simultaneously*.

Answer (score 1):

because each task blocked on "latch.await();", the queued tasks in LinkedBlockingQueue<> will never have chance to run. that makes deadlocks.  You should latch.countDown() in each task. but latch.await() in the main thread.